# Replace matching differently encoded tags

Tags: bash, macos, character-encoding

I have a [file](https://github.com/vicner/eu4/blob/master/rights_of_man_l_ukrainian.txt) that was translated by someone else. I don't know what encoding the person used, but seems that tags `$TAG$`, that were not supposed to be translated, are converted to another set of characters (i.e. even though the tags look the same, the ASCII characters they include, are not the characters from the [original source file](https://github.com/vicner/eu4_eng/blob/master/rights_of_man_l_english.txt)). This is messing up further substitution of the Cyrillic characters to extended ASCII-chars (which is not part of the question). So my replacement script replaces the tags (at least partially) as well.

What is the best way to replace the tags in the corrupted file by the corresponding tags from the original one?

The files have to be UTF-8 (with BOM), EOL=LF.

Mac bash preferably, thanks.

Comment: Seems like only the corresponding letters were replaced in the corrupted file. E.g. `А-A, І-I, К-K, etc. 
Maybe I can replace them with the Latin ones. Can try it later at night though..

Comment: Still, would be good to know other ways to resolve the issue. How would I replace a whole tag by the correct one, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

one strategy is to make a list of the current utf8 tags, a list of the ascii tags, line them up, then use `paste` and `sed` to replace the utf8 tags with ascii tags in the ukranian file:

```
grep -o '\$[^\$]\+\$' rights_of_man_l_ukrainian.txt | sort | uniq > utf8.tags.list
grep -o '\$[^\$]\+\$' rights_of_man_l_english.txt | sort | uniq > ascii.tags.list

# now, manually edit ascii.tags.list so that each line number has
# the correct replacement for that line of utf8.tags.list, e.g.,
# by using:
vimdiff utf8.tags.list ascii.tags.list

# escape the $s
sed -i 's/\$/\\$/g' utf8.tags.list ascii.tags.list

# now substitute the tags
paste utf8.tags.list ascii.tags.list |
  while read n k; do
    sed "s/$n/$k/g" rights_of_man_l_ukrainian.txt
  done > rights_of_man_l_ukrainian.ascii-tags.txt
```

a more satisfying way is to automatically generate the utf to ascii conversion table. on mac, `iconv` and `perl Text::Unidecode` both turn the utf8 strings into garbage. on linux, `konwert` shows promise here.

ps: it looks like there is another problem as well, though: two missing tags:

FORCEBREAKALLIANCEDESC:1 "If they accept, both countries' opinion of us will decrease and $WITH|Y$ will get a Casus Belli on us.\nThis will also create a truce between $COUNTRY|Y$ and us, as well as lower their trust of us by $TRUSTCOST|R$. Otherwise, we will lose $PRESTIGE$ Prestige."

vs

FORCEBREAKALLIANCEDESC:1 "Якщо вони погодяться, то ставлення обох країн до нас зменшиться, а держава $WIТН|Y$ отримає привід для війни з нами.\nТакож буде оголошено перемир'я між державою $СОUNТRY|Y$ та нами, а також зменшить їхню довіру до нас. В іншому випадку, ми втратимо $РRЕSТIGЕ$ престижу."

(missing $TRUSTCOST|R$)

and

stat_game_country_desc_server:0 "$VAL|Y$% of players this month played as $NAME|Y$."

vs

stat_game_country_desc_server:0 "В середньому, в цьому місяці у гравців відбулося близько $VАL|Y$ лих."

(missing $NAME|Y$)